# Find number of functions such that $f(f(x)) = f(x)$, where $f: \{1,2,3,4,5\}\to \{1,2,3,4,5\}$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, random-variables, recursion

> Consider set $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and functions $f:A\to A.$ Find the number of functions such that $f\big(f(x)\big) = f(x)$ holds.

I tried using recursion but could not form a recursion relation. I tried counting the cases manually, but it was too exhaustive and impractical. I tried drawing/mapping but that too included counting by making cases. Random variable was another approach I tried but couldn't make a summation.

A general idea for such problems is needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider cases corresponding to the size of $f$'s range. For example, how many $f$ with the required property have $|f(A)|=1$?

Comment: Functions $f$ for which $f(f(x))=f(x)$ for all $x$ in the domain of $f$ are known as idempotent functions.

Comment: If $y = f(x)$ for some $x$, then $f(y) = y$. So, $f$ acts as the identity on some set (ie $f(y) =y$ in that set) and elements outside that set are mapped into it by $f$. How many ways to pick the identity acting set? How many ways to map into from what's left over?

Answer (score 1):

If a variable $x$ is in the range of $f(x)$, then $f(x)=x$. This means that we can effectively categorize the potential functions by their range. The number of functions that have a given range is $n^{5-n}$, with $n$ being the number of values in the range. The number of ranges that have $n$ values in them is $\frac{5!}{n!(5-n)!}$. This means that the total number of functions is $$\sum_{n=1}^5\frac{5!}{n!(5-n)!}n^{5-n}$$which comes out to be $196$.

Comment: This is not correct.  We do not demand that $f(f(x))=x$, which is what you are trying to calculate.  For example, $f(1)=1, f(2)=1$ is an acceptable start.  For what you are trying to do, there are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ with one swap.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks for the clarification. I believe I fixed my answer to solve the actual problem

Comment: Yeah, this answer is correct atm.